# Android customize stackview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I"m trying to customize the StackView widget to look a little bit different.

The stackview default order and view is this :

[image: Stackview Default view]

And i"m trying to get to something more like this : 
[image]

Any help will be appreciated

Shimi

Comment: Hey Have you achieve like second image shown in your question if yes can you post your android.

Comment: Same problem here. Thanks in advance for any comments!

Comment: Please follow the link http://stackoverflow.com/a/28255913/1881611

Answer (score -3):

try checking out the source code of [StackView](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/widget/StackView.java/?v=source) .

as a first step , you can play with the parameter called "PERSPECTIVE_SHIFT_FACTOR_X" and "PERSPECTIVE_SHIFT_FACTOR_Y" .