# How to implement customized stack view in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, customization, android-view, stackview

I have searched the internet but I couldn't find some good explanation or advice.
Basically, I want to implement this functionality.

[image]
on slide down

[image]

[image]

I used the StackView class and all I get is this "diagonal" stack

[image]

I want views to be one behind another, as in the pictures above.

Similar question is asked here -> [Android customize stackview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14029048/android-customize-stackview), but I couldn't find any satisfying answers.

I have read the code for StackView as suggested, but honestly, I don't know how would I customize it to get what I want.
When I change the value of PERSPECTIVE_SHIFT_FACTOR_X or 
PERSPECTIVE_SHIFT_FACTOR_Y nothing changes and I get the same "diagonal view". Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: Please consider starring this feature request: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37076423

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Feel free to use my library available [here](https://github.com/blipinsk/FlippableStackView).

[image]

It does exactly what you want and is based on the `ViewPager` so you can use it with just a typical `PagerAdapter` of your choice.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Could you please tell me how could I modify the implementation to support swiping multiple cards (not just one) with one 'strong' swipe?

Comment: Cant really think of any "quick-and-easy" solutions... I think you would have to implement something similiar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14969879/1993204 , but supporting `VerticalViewPager` instead of the horizontal one. BTW feel free to accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: @blipinsk can I customise your lib where I can swipe views to left and right to discard? I want to give effect to stack view as Tinder like swipe functionality.

Comment: Hello @BartoszLipinski Thanks for the awesome library . One question is there any way to have vertical and horizontal flip with init Thanks.

Comment: @Bartosz Lipinski Thanks for library, it looks great! Is there a way to implement my own adapter so that every fragment will include different data, for example Editexts with different names?

Comment: @Mor sure thing... it just works with a regular `PagerAdapter`. You can use e.g. `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and overide `getItem` to return a different `Fragment` for a particular position inside `ViewPager`

Comment: Hi, any ideas on how to change the item display at front programatically? I would like to display the StackView but move it using two buttons. Thanks!

Comment: @Lancelot I answered you in the issue you've created over at github.

Comment: @BartekLipinski Thank you!!!! Just saw it. I'm testing it now, in case anyone else is looking at this, as a normal ViewPager it has the method setCurrentItem available.

Answer (score 8):

You can't change the original `PERSPECTIVE_SHIFT_FACTOR_X` because it's a private field.

`StackView` uses many classes which have *package visibility* and are only usable in package *android.widget*.

Furthermore some of those classes are pre-compiled and the source is nowhere to be found, so you can't just *copy-paste* them and create your own custom `StackView` from zero.

You can make the views appear in a column by overriding `onLayout`, but once you animate them, their positions are changed back to the default. Sadly the view animations are done in private methods of `StackView` so nothing you can do about that either.

You're better of creating your own class that does this, and you can reference the code used in the `StackView` source. Creating such a class could be a lot of work and it's definitely not in the scope of a single question.